# A connection between nonplanar complete graphs and the alternating group?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, simple-groups

I went to an undergrad's senior honors thesis presentation a few days ago. She was discussing crossing numbers and mentioned that [complete graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph) $K_n$ are nonplanar iff $n \geq 5$.

?Coincidentally? $A_n$ (the alternating group of even permutations) is a *nonabelian* simple group iff $n \geq 5$.

I know there are many connections between graph theory/finite geometry and group theory. It seems that many simple groups (especially sporadics) have roots in weird graphs and odd geometric objects. So this led me to wonder...

> Is there a connection between $K_n$ being nonplanar and $A_n$ being nonabelian simple (when $n \geq 5$)?

...or maybe this is just a coincidence.

**EDIT:**  I just posted this on Mathoverflow to see if I get any response there. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150746/a-connection-between-nonplanar-complete-graphs-and-the-alternating-group

Comment: Your statement isn't quite correct -- Alt(3) is simple (though it isn't generally mentioned in the classification of finite simple groups since it's included in the "cyclic of prime order" family). So any such connection would have to take this into account.

Comment: Yes, technically you're right, but the cyclics of prime order don't really fit with nonabelian simple -- they almost shouldn't count. They're kind of the "trivial" simple groups. :)

Comment: I have reposted this on mathoverflow to see if I get any response there... http://mathoverflow.net/questions/150746/a-connection-between-nonplanar-complete-graphs-and-the-alternating-group